# How to use session attributes and store data using the persistentattribute in ask-sdk-2

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I want to store user's data such that the next time the user uses this particular skill it remembers his name and number using the employee id he is entering and I am using ASK-SDK 2.0.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a persistence adapter provided by the Alexa SDK (eg the DynamoDB adapter). When you use it by default the primary key of the generated table is the userId (it comes in the request to your lambda and is unique to each user activation of a skill e.g. similar to being unique to an app installation in the mobile world). You can change the primary key via a key generator function, for example you could change it to make the primary key be the employee id. Take a look at this example:

https://gist.github.com/germanviscuso/70c979f671660fea811ccfb63801f936

you could change the key generator function [here](https://gist.github.com/germanviscuso/70c979f671660fea811ccfb63801f936#file-index-js-L39) to return the employee id. But my advice is that you don't use a key generation function at all, store transparently by userId and save a persistent attribute called employee id.